# Android Emulator for Xamarin in Visial Studio 2017 using Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I just started with Xamarin and installed it. The only way I could find to do this currently was by downloading Visual Studio 2017.

I opened the program and went to run my first Xamarin Android program but there are no emulators available. I  checked it out and from what I have read the new emulator only runs on Windows 8 and above. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

I am sure there is something simple I am missing. Is there any way to run other emulators for Android. I tried Genymotion which I used a lot before, but now it has become expensive and I don't even know if will work in this case.

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you try VS emulators?

Comment: That is the Visual Studio Emulator that requires windows 8

Comment: @NicholasMuir If your hardware has an Intel processor and supports Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality, then use Google's Android accelerated x86 AVDs (via Intel Haxm).