# Can I debug an Android Xamarin Forms app on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have a Windows 7 PC and a Windows 10 PC.  I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and specifically Mobile Development with .NET (all components) on both.

I am able to develop an Xamarin Forms app on the Windows 10 PC, which supports Android; IOS and UWP.

I have attempted to create an Xamarin app for Android on the Windows 7 PC.   When I attempt to launch any emulator on the windows 7 PC; I see this message:

[image]

I have Googled this and I have tried:

```
1) Changing the platform of the app from AnyCPU to x86.
2) Reinstalling Visual Studio 2017
```

One post I found earlier advised me to use the Google Emulators instead of the Windows emulators.

1) Am I using the Google emulators in my screenshot above (notice that the emulators say: "Google APIs")?

Or

2) Do I have to install Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio) and do native Android development in order to use the Google emulators?

Comment: Please update to the lastest version of VS2017 to check if the problem still exist. Through [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/535095/view.html), this problem has been fixed in [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Comment: @Jack Hua, does this apply to windows 7? Thanks.

Comment: Check the [2019/system-requirements here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements).

Comment: Also, I found a link for [system-requirements-for-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/system-requirements-for-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android?view=vs-2017), it says you need a  Windows 8 and later versions. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057750/android-emulator-for-xamarin-in-visial-studio-2017-using-windows-7) and try what sushi said may help.

Comment: @Jach Hua, yes I saw that.  It is very confusing.  Some sites say it is supported and some say it is not.  Do you know the difference between a windows emulator and a google emulator? Can you use google emulators inside visual studio or are they used when developing native apps inside android studio? Thanks.

Comment: I think we should trust the official document. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Android emulators. You can try run your project in a real device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you cannot run an **official** emulator on Windows 7.

The [Windows system requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) for Android Studio says:

*The Android Emulator only supports 64-bit Windows*

However, it seems likely that [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/) will work - worth downloading and testing.

As a general caution, I've found the Android toolchain for deploying Xamarin Forms to be the most fragile part of Forms development. It's quite possible you can go to a lot of effort to set this up to still run into weird, impossible-to-diagnose errors with Visual Studio.

**Update**
As you have 64 bit Windows 7, it's worth trying.

**General advice** try using plain Android Studio and building a trivial app from a template within it. This applies to testing any environment, be it virtual or with attached devices. If this doesn't work, the added layers of Xamarin Forms are unlikely to.

Oh, and seriously, don't just test things on the simulators. You really need to test on hardware.

Comment: The windows 7 PC is 64 bit.  In your link it says windows 7 is supported or have I misunderstood?